# How can I debug, templated binding in knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I have a series of templates within templates. I will put only the code that is closer to the problem, since other parts seem to work alright.

The frame template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="frame">
    <fieldset class='frame'>
        <legend data-bind="text: label"></legend>
        <!-- ko foreach: { data: children, as: 'child' } -->
        <!-- ko template: {name: child.controlType } -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </fieldset>
</script>
```

The table template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="table">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="tableAction">
            <a class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" data-bind="click: action"></a> <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: center">
                        #
                    </th>
                    <!-- ko foreach: {data: $data.rowTemplate().children, as: 'column' } -->
                    <th>
                        <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
                    </th>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </tr>
                <!-- ko foreach: { data: rows, as: 'row' } -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
                    </td>
                    <!-- ko foreach: { data: row, as: 'item' } -->
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: item"></span>
                    </td>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The Control base class:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />

import ko = require("knockout");

class Control {
    id: any;
    ref: any;
    index: number;
    label: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    min: any;
    max: any;
    value: KnockoutObservable<any>;
    maxLength: any;
    height: any;
    columnCount: any;
    rowCount: any;    
    column: any;
    row: any;
    css: any;
    controlType: any;
    xml: any;
    children: KnockoutObservableArray<Control>;
    action: any;
    valueObj: any;
    isEditable: boolean;

    constructor(id: any, ref: any, index: number, label: any, min: any, max: any, value: any, maxLength: any, columnCount: any, rowCount: any, column: any, row: any, css: any, controlType: any, valueObj: any, isEditable: boolean, xml: any) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ref = ref;
        this.index = index;
        this.label = ko.observable<string>(label);
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.value = ko.observable<any>(value).extend({ notify: "always" });
        this.valueObj = valueObj;
        var self = this;
        this.value.subscribe(function () {
            if (self.valueObj && self.value() && self.valueObj.value !== self.value()) {
                self.valueObj.hasChanges = true;
                self.valueObj.value = self.value();
            }
        });
        this.maxLength = maxLength;        
        this.columnCount = columnCount;
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;
        this.css = css;
        this.controlType = controlType;
        this.xml = xml;
        this.children = ko.observableArray<Control>([]);
        this.isEditable = isEditable;

    }
} 

export = Control
```

The TableControl:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />

import ko = require("knockout");
import Control = require("Models/Control"); 
import TableRowControl = require("Models/TableRowControl"); 

class TableControl extends Control {    
    rows: KnockoutObservable<any>;
    rowTemplate: KnockoutObservable<TableRowControl>;

    constructor(id: any, ref: any, index: number, label: any, min: any, max: any, value: any, maxLength: any, columnCount: any, rowCount: any, column: any, row: any, css: any, controlType: any, valueObj: any, isEditable: boolean, xml: any) {
        super(id, ref, index, label, min, max, value, maxLength, columnCount, rowCount, column, row, css, controlType, valueObj, isEditable, xml);        
        this.rows = ko.observableArray<any>([]);
        this.rowTemplate = ko.observable<TableRowControl>(new TableRowControl(id + "Template", ref, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "", "item", null, false, ""));
    }
} 

export = TableControl;
```

The table row control:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />

import ko = require("knockout");
import Control = require("Models/Control");

class TableRowControl extends Control {
    constructor(id: any, ref: any, index: number, label: any, min: any, max: any, value: any, maxLength: any, columnCount: any, rowCount: any, column: any, row: any, css: any, controlType: any, valueObj: any, isEditable: boolean, xml: any) {
        super(id, ref, index, label, min, max, value, maxLength, columnCount, rowCount, column, row, css, controlType, valueObj, isEditable, xml);

    }
}

export = TableRowControl;
```

The host ViewModel (Sample or reduced code one):

```
class ConfigurationItemDetailBlade extends BladeBase {
    item: KnockoutObservable<any>;
    controls: KnockoutObservableArray<any>;

    someMethod() {
        this.controls.removeAll()

        for (var j = 0; j < item.children().length; j++) {
            var control = item.children[j];
            this.controls.push(control);
        }
    }
}
```

I am using typescript with knockout 3.3.0 and requireJs, the idea was when a control is added to the list it would show on the page, but I can't get the label to show in the table header, and when I attempt things like either before the table or with the header:

```
<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></pre>
<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($parent), null, 2)"></pre>
```

I get the following error message

```
0x80004005 - JavaScript runtime error: Unspecified error.
```

I have tried multiple ways to move things around the table, change the name "column" to not using it at all or as column.label, with or without parentheses, and I did verify the content by putting a break point where I add the control to the collection, and it does contain a table, and each element has a label set, and it also generates the  element in the result page.
So everything is there but the label is not printing.

EDIT:

After the suggestions I tried the following:

```
<span data-bind="text: $data.label, attr: { title: 'DATA', value: JSON.stringify($data.rowTemplate) }"></span>
```

AND:

```
<span data-bind="text: $data.label, attr: { title: 'DATA', value: JSON.stringify($data) }"></span>
```

Only the second yields results, but the interesting part is that it does not show the data for rowTemplate, although it does exist.
The list of controls has a diversity of controls that use one of the classes defined above, the one that is specially causing trouble is the TableControl one, and the boxing of the type hides the property. NOT SURE WHAT TO DO THERE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding failures mostly fall into these categories:

- Scope related
- Broken syntax
- Property references that are invalid because the observable (that will contain the object with the property) has yet to be initialised

Use binding to set a title attribute on everything that participates in binding, like this:

```
data-binding="attr: { title: 'anything you like, really' }, value:... }"
```

Run up your app and then examine your binding elements by hovering the mouse over them, to find out where binding stops. This will give you a fairly good idea of what part of your mark-up is busted.

Comment: It seems like inheritance make the whole thing fail

Comment: Alas I have no experience with typescript so I can't help there but I do have one other observation to make, try using online templates because there are glitches with named templates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use google chrome inspector. Put some breakpoints (using debugger reserved word) on your javascript file and then using option "step over" to see where is the place on your code that break the app:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging